# What are the correct texture coordinates for a quad consisting of 2 triangles

Tags: webgl

I cant figure out why this is happening.
I draw a quad (of 2 triangles) with the following vertices

```
let data = [
     -0.5, -0.5, 0,
     0.5, -0.5, 0, 
     0.5, 0.5, 0,
    -0.5, -0.5, 0,
     0.5, 0.5, 0,
    -0.5, 0.5, 0
]
```

And the following texture coordinates

```
let textureData = [0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1];
```

which gives me for this texture 
[image: original texture]

this output[image]

Another error is that the texture is not transparent, but i call

```
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

every frame i draw the texture.
So my Questions are, what are the right texture coordinates and how can draw a texutere with a transparent background.

Edit :
Loading Texture

```
  this._image.onload = () => {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._textureBuffer);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, this._image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
};
```

Cant post more code but short summary

- gl.bindBuffer(vbo)
- gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0)
- gl.bindTexture()
- gl.uniform1i(sampler2D,0)
- draw stuff

Edit 2 (How i create Buffer that contains vertices)

```
 this._vertexBufferObject= gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._vertexBufferObject);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

    this._textureBufferObject= gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._textureBufferObject);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(textureData), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
```

Edit 3: Draw-Method and applyTexture

```
  draw(camera) {
let gl = Core.mGL;
// gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
// gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._vertexBufferObject);
this._shaderProgram.activateProgram(camera.vpMatrix);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._shaderProgram.vertexAttributeLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._shaderProgram.textureAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

this._shaderProgram.loadTransformation(this._transformation.transform());
this._shaderProgram.applyTexture(this._textureBuffer, gl.TEXTURE_2D);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this._data.length / 3);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
this._shaderProgram.deactivateProgram(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
```

}

```
  applyTexture(id, type) {
this._gl.activeTexture(this._gl.TEXTURE0);
this._gl.bindTexture(type, id);
this._gl.uniform1i(this._mouseSamplerLocation, 0);
```

}

Comment: My bad, its just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two more texture vertices

0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1

to

0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 
**0,0, 1,1, 0,1**

The correct texture coordinates depend on your position vertices so it seems fine.

And I guess your texture is not transparent. It might be just with white background.

**#update1**

Please do this
after glTexImage2D()

```
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

or just do

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

And don't do unbindtexture  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);

**#update2**

```
this._shaderProgram.activateProgram(camera.vpMatrix);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._vertexBufferObject);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._shaderProgram.vertexAttributeLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._textureBufferObject); // **missing**
gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._shaderProgram.textureAttributeLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Makes no difference, exactly the same image .

Comment: i edit my question. I'am also loading a cubemap which works fine, so i know the other code is working. If you want to see something special feel free to ask

Comment: @lolio I want to see the code that generates a buffer which contains vertices

Comment: @lolio you don't tell opengl about your buffer's layout using gl.vertexAttribPointer() if you do, let me see

Comment: my question is updated, if relevant parts are missing please tell me

Comment: @lolio can you please call glEnableVertexAttribArray(each_id); before vertexAttribPointer(...)? so like glEnableVertexAttribArray(this._shaderProgram.vertexAttributeLocation) and so on

Comment: i checked this and this is called like you said. Also i want to mention that loading a CUBEMAP works fine. So maybe there is a error in the texture(because of transparency) or the texture filter is wrong...

Comment: @lolio but your fist texture coordinate was wrong, and I still guess it is texture or position vertices problem because the same thing happens to me when I put wrong indices or texture vertices

Comment: alright, i will check this one more time. Thank you

Comment: @lolio Updated my question. One thing was wrong with your mipmap option or just don't mipmap

Comment: this was missing gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._textureBufferObject); pls update your answer and i will accept since you helped me

Comment: This answer has no educational value and is likely to be useless to future readers as you're not clearly identifying the underlying issue nor are you explaining the proposed changes.